# How to host an OData V4 Web API on Azure

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have an OData V4 Web API( .NET Framework 4.6.1) hosted on On-Prem IIS. Instead of making it Internet Facing, I want to host it on Azure. What are my options here? What are the best practices to host it? Do I have to create a new Web API Project inside Azure? What Services do I need to subscribe to?

This web service will be consumed by Virtual Entities under MS CRM
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/virtual-entity-walkthrough-using-odata-provider

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deploy it to Azure App Service, The web app type should not make a difference but Web API should be the most correct.

If you don't want to expose it to everyone, you can use Access Restrictions on your azure web app by adding a rule that allows specific IP range to access the API URL

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. using Azure Relay service - Hybrid connection ([Relay Service link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-relay/relay-what-is-it))
2. S2S VPN - Another option, which helps to expose the service to a particular Azure Virtual Network.
   ([Reference link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vpn-gateway/vpn-gateway-howto-site-to-site-resource-manager-portal))

Can you tell me what are the services going to consume the service, so that I can provide accurate solution

Comment: Hi Arun, This is just an OData V4 Service to be consumed by Virtual Entities in MS CRM 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/customize/virtual-entity-walkthrough-using-odata-provider

Comment: I believe you need to expose your service to the internet or particular to Dyanmics 365. If you are using AAD then this link might help you to achieve the desired result securely https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-add-on-premises-application.